# Insert TextView in other XML file than current ContentView

Tags: android

I want to insert a TextView into a LinearLayout that's in a different XML file that is being used as layout for a ListView. But it seems that I can't access the LinearLayout that's in the other XML file.

I run a loop that gets category titles, and for each title I wanna create a TextView with the title.

**How I insert the TextView**

```
LinearLayout Layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.itemDesign); //When debugging I can see "Layout" is just null. itemDesign is also not in main.xml.
TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setText(CatName);
Layout.addView(title);
```

**XML used by ListView "single_list_item.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemDesign"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"/>
    <!-- Description Label -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/email_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Layout XML files don't exist in runtime, you cannot access them. Anyway, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I run a loop that gets category titles, and for each title I wanna create a TextView with the title.

Comment: I can also say that, the ID called itemDesign is the id of LinearLayout in Single_list_item.xml, and it seems that I can't access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to inflate your view. In `getView()` of adapter class

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
```

Then to access your `TextView`s

```
TextView firstTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.some_id);
```

**[All about LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)**

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are not setting the activity content view before using `findViewById()`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
```

After that initialize your text view, and add width, height params to that. Then there should be no problems in adding that text view to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try invalidating the layout after you add the TextView:

```
Layout.addView(title);
Layout.invalidate();
```

I'm still not entirely sure what you want to achieve, maybe you could give us some more information regarding what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a new ListView item based on an xml file, you need to inflate it first. Then you can call `findViewById()` on the resulting view to get the children.

```
LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
LinearLayout listItemLayout = (LinearLayout)inf.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, null);

TextView nameLabel = (TextView) listItemLayout.findViewById(R.id.name_label);
```